# AnonymousType#1 to int

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
 var _maxID = from a in db.Articles
              where a.CategoryId == categoryID
              orderby a.Id descending
              select new {ID = a.ID};    

 int maxID = _maxID.FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

This code gives me an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Typo in yhe maxID assignment statement ("Id" instead of "ID"). Try this:
 int maxID = _maxID.FirstOrDefault().Id;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it simpler and just use the [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) function.

```
var _ids = from a in db.Articles
           where a.CategoryId == categoryID
           select a.ID;    

int maxID = _ids.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use FirstOrDefault if you are not going to check for null before accessing the value. Just use First() then.

Second, you could select a.ID directly.

```
[...]
orderby a.Id descending
select a.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use(but you have to check for null before accessing)

```
int  maxID = Convert.ToInt32(_maxID.FirstOrDefault().ID);
//or
int? maxID = _maxID.FirstOrDefault().ID as int;
//or
int maxID = (int)_maxID.FirstOrDefault().ID;
```